# Magit-process shows every frame of dynamic "animated" output

Tags: magit, term

I'm working with a project that has a pre-commit hook that outputs an "animated" progress bar and updates the output to show which step is completed.  In the magit-process buffer it shows every frame in the output window rather than in-place as in the terminal.  Is it possible to get this to work in the emacs buffers?

Comment: Emacs buffers are not terminal emulators, so emulating this will require implementing what that hook is exactly making use of.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the manual entries on process handling. Particularly <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Output from Processes` and `(elisp) Sentinels`

`magit-start-process` returns a process object with `magit-process-sentinel` and `magit-process-filter` attached, and actually mentions that these can be overridden (e.g. with 'after' advice).

term.el's `term-exec` uses `term-sentinel` and `term-emulate-terminal` to handle the process running in the terminal.

One suspects that you could integrate the `term` behaviour with the `magit` process handling, but you would surely need to experiment with this yourself. I have no idea whether there are any conflicts that you would need to deal with, or what sort of complications you may encounter.

You might alternatively, as wasamasa comments, implement a custom filter which handles only the specific features that are required. If you're happy to ascertain the control codes which specifically need to be handled, and figure out what needs to be done to support them.